# Woocommerce Custom shop page with infinte load

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woothemes

Hi currently I am creating a woocommerce custom shop page template .

For this, I have created a new template inside my theme page called custom-shop  & I have created new page called my shop and assign custom-shop template.

I have 3 main category called car , bus, boat .  Now  I am going to display each category  with its description and product details

So I write the following code in my `cutom-shop` template(`custom-shop.php`)

```
custom-shop.php

/*
Template name: custom-shop

*/

BLOCKS OF CODE 

<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Car</h2>
    <p class="description">Car Description</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="40" columns="4" category="car"]'); ?> 
</div>

<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Bus</h2>
    <p class="description">Bus Description</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="40" columns="4" category="bus"]'); ?> 
</div>

<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Boat</h2>
    <p class="description">Boat Description</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="40" columns="4" category="boat"]'); ?>    
</div>
```

Here Everything is working fine . But the **problem is the page load time is high** , because every product is loading together . How can i solve this issue , how can i implement infinite load ?

**What I need is** first display car and it's 4 products then user scroll down display other products in car . After car products finished then display bus and it's 4 products , like this

**what I tried is**

After searching I found a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ and i t help to resolve some issue and i used this plugin code

```
<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Car</h2>
    <p class="description">Car Description</p>
    <?php do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="product" columns="4" css_classes="products" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade"  taxonomy="product_cat" taxonomy_terms="car" taxonomy_operator="IN" button_label=""]'); ?>  
</div>

<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Bus</h2>
    <p class="description">Bus Description</p>
    <?php do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="product" columns="4" css_classes="products" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade"  taxonomy="product_cat" taxonomy_terms="car" taxonomy_operator="IN" button_label=""]'); ?>  
</div>

<div class="category-block">
    <h2>Car</h2>
    <p class="description">Boat Description</p>
    <?php do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="product" columns="4" css_classes="products" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade"  taxonomy="product_cat" taxonomy_terms="car" taxonomy_operator="IN" button_label=""]'); ?>  
</div>
```

But here the problem is that when I scroll down it will first show car and it's 4 products , then bus and it's 4 products  again load other products for car . So it's not also proper solution .

Please help , to solve this issue .

Comment: Can't you incorporate some infinite scroll plugin, say YITH infinite scroll plugin or so?
I think you can customize that as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

actually if you want to do it by yourself, I will just suggest you to follow [this guide, cmmon click me!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_lU7_JUS2g&list=PLriKzYyLb28kpEnFFi9_vJWPf5-_7d3rX&index=33) -> It will be lots more helpful than any huge reply in here.
This guy goes trough all the ajax proceses that you will need to use. Also you can just parse a piece of his code and get it all done. **Shortly, you just need ajax.** more explicit -> you can see in this video

I will paste in here the code result of the guide bypassing all the small procedures for a better understanding

First of all he created a template to output the content wich looks like this

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header text-center">

    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) .'" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>'); ?>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php echo sunset_posted_meta(); ?>
    </div>

</header>

<div class="entry-content">

    <?php if( sunset_get_attachment() ): ?>

        <a class="standard-featured-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="standard-featured background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo sunset_get_attachment(); ?>);"></div>
        </a>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="button-container text-center">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-sunset"><?php _e( 'Read More' ); ?></a>
    </div>

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php echo sunset_posted_footer(); ?>
</footer>

</article>
```

Next step was to validate in wp the ajax function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
function sunset_load_more() {

  $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;
  $prev = $_POST["prev"];
  $archive = $_POST["archive"];

  if( $prev == 1 && $_POST["page"] != 1 ){
    $paged = $_POST["page"]-1;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged
);

if( $archive != '0' ){

    $archVal = explode( '/', $archive );

    $type = ( $archVal[1] == "category" ? "category_name" : $archVal[1] );

    $args[ $type ] = $archVal[2];

    $page_trail = '/' . $archVal[1] . '/' . $archVal[2] . '/';

} else {
    $page_trail = '/';
}

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ):

    echo '<div class="page-limit" data-page="' . $page_trail . 'page/' . $paged . '">';

    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';

else:

    echo 0;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

die();

}
function sunset_check_paged( $num = null ){

$output = '';

if( is_paged() ){ $output = 'page/' . get_query_var( 'paged' ); }

if( $num == 1 ){
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ? 1 : get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    return $paged;
} else {
    return $output;
}

}
```

And the last step will be the AJAX function itself.

```
/* Ajax functions */
$(document).on('click','.sunset-load-more:not(.loading)', function(){

    var that = $(this);
    var page = $(this).data('page');
    var newPage = page+1;
    var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
    var prev = that.data('prev');
    var archive = that.data('archive');

    if( typeof prev === 'undefined' ){
        prev = 0;
    }

    if( typeof archive === 'undefined' ){
        archive = 0;
    }

    that.addClass('loading').find('.text').slideUp(320);
    that.find('.sunset-icon').addClass('spin');

    $.ajax({

        url : ajaxurl,
        type : 'post',
        data : {

            page : page,
            prev : prev,
            archive : archive,
            action: 'sunset_load_more'

        },
        error : function( response ){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function( response ){

            if( response == 0 ){

                $('.sunset-posts-container').append( '<div class="text-center"><h3>You reached the end of the line!</h3><p>No more posts to load.</p></div>' );
                that.slideUp(320);

            } else {

                setTimeout(function(){

                    if( prev == 1 ){
                        $('.sunset-posts-container').prepend( response );
                        newPage = page-1;
                    } else {
                        $('.sunset-posts-container').append( response );
                    }

                    if( newPage == 1 ){

                        that.slideUp(320);

                    } else {

                        that.data('page', newPage);

                        that.removeClass('loading').find('.text').slideDown(320);
                        that.find('.sunset-icon').removeClass('spin');

                    }

                    revealPosts();

                }, 1000);

            }


        }

    });

});

/* scroll function */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( Math.abs( scroll - last_scroll ) > $(window).height()*0.1 ) {
        last_scroll = scroll;

        $('.page-limit').each(function( index ){

            if( isVisible( $(this) ) ){

                history.replaceState( null, null, $(this).attr("data-page") );
                return(false);

            }

        });

    }

});

/* helper functions */
function revealPosts(){

    var posts = $('article:not(.reveal)');
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){

        if( i >= posts.length ) return false;

        var el = posts[i];
        $(el).addClass('reveal').find('.sunset-carousel-thumb').carousel();

        i++

    }, 200);

}

function isVisible( element ){

    var scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var el_top = $(element).offset().top;
    var el_height = $(element).height();
    var el_bottom = el_top + el_height;
    return ( ( el_bottom - el_height*0.25 > scroll_pos ) && ( el_top < ( scroll_pos+0.5*window_height ) ) );

}
});
```

I would suggest you to follow the guide created by alecadd because it will be much easier to understand the process and suit it for your purposes. Hope it's enough now!

Cheers.